# Random Number list help C# Windows Form

Tags: windows, winforms

I am trying to generate 100 random numbers to display at the same time between 0 and 1000 in C# windows forms and I'm stuck. I can do it in a console application but can't translate it to windows forms.

I have this code

```
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    MessageBox.Show(rand.Next(0,1001).ToString());
```

Is there a function like `NextBytes` for random numbers only? I can't find one.

Comment: You could add the random numbers to a ListBox, or some other control, maybe?...

Comment: How do you want it displayed?

Comment: the same code is working on windows form application, what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is it generates only one random number. I need 100 random numbers listed preferably in a text box or the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Umm.. Like this?

```
Random rand = new Random();
        string s=null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            s +=rand.Next(0, 1001).ToString()+"," ;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```